# Transform PHP String (of html source) into jQuery Object Dollar Sign $?

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-selectors, encode

Lets say i have a full source string of html page (in PHP), like:

```
<?php
$html_source = '
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="class1">Hello!</div>
            <div class="class2">World</div>
        </body>
    </html>'; //PHP
?>
```

Then i want to use that php String as a jQuery `$` Object for the purpose to use like:

```
alert(
    $("div.class1").html(); //jQuery
);
```

So how do i convert the PHP string into jQuery Dollar Sign `$` ?

***Note***:
This is because my situation is... i have a Database contains full html pages sources. Then i have to parse them out but not all of whole page. Some DOM filtered areas. Like, "right panel" of that page source inside. Thats the problem.

Comment: You can't use a PHP variable in a script on the clientside, it's outputted to the browser on the serverside and is gone.

Comment: You seem a little confused as to the differing roles of PHP and jQuery. PHP is server-side and happens long before jQuery enters the game. jQuery is client-side. The two have no relationship and so there is no question of conversion from one to the other. PHP can merely output a string to the client, which could then be picked up and handled by jQuery.

Comment: Hello Utkanos, i know them very well. Just consider all possible conditions like me, that i have a Database contains html pages sources. Then i have to parse them out but not all whole page. Some DOM filtered areas. Like, "right panel" of that page source. So what would you do?

Comment: Well it depends if you want to handle the DOM on the client or on the server. You said jQuery, so I assume the former. In which case, PHP cannot talk to jQuery directly - it can only output to it. If server side, PHP has its own DOM traversal/manipulation functions - see the docs for DOMDocument.

Comment: By your update, you'd probably be doing it server-side to avoid sending unneeded data and wasting bandwidth on both ends.

Comment: Wasting Bandwidth or whatever i don't have choice to care about. Just the way is all i need. I need the data strings to be parsed out.

Comment: Quentin's answer will suffice for client-side parsing.

Answer (score 3):

Frist, make the string JavaScript safe. Given a string, `json_encode` will make it JS safe (although not JSON).

You can then output it into a script block in your HTML and pass that to the jQuery function.

```
<script>
var foo = $(<?php echo json_encode($html_source); ?>);
</script>
```

Comment: `var foo` then? How do i make the parsing like jQuery? How will it be looks like for this normal scenario: `$("div.class2).html`

Comment: Using the context selector `$("div.class1", foo).html()` or more explicit: `foo.find('div.class2').html()`

Comment: hmmm.. ya it works, but NOT directly as the `$`. So it means, only the `.find` method will work. Won't work without it. :T

Answer (score 1):

Try using Zend framework/library's [Zend_Dom_Query](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.query.html) part. It understands most of CSS2, and you can always fall back to xpath when you need some more powerful.

If you would like to have a more JQuery like look-and-feel, you can try the [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) project too.

Comment: Hmmm.. seems useful. But let it be a last way. Can't i directly use as `jQuery` ?

Comment: There's no Javascript vm written in php (at least not that i know of), I guess you could fire up a [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) or a [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) vm with fork() but it's probably a bad idea, and still don't solve the getting data in/out from the vm problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the html part or if you need to handle this with php than you can use php dom document extension.

Comment: This is because my situation is.. i have a Database contains full html pages sources. Then i have to parse them out but not all of whole page. Some DOM filtered areas. Like, "right panel" of that page source inside. Thats the problem.

Comment: Than go for dom document but one thing when you are using dom document the html has to be pure XHTML like than it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<script>
     var myStr = $(<?php echo $html_source; ?>);
</script>
```